# While trying to resolve a cross-store reference, the SID of the target principal could not be resolved. The error code is 1788

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I came across few similar articles but it didn't help to fix the problem.

This is the code snippet i am using:

```
private void GetUsersFromGroup(
        PrincipalContext principalContext,
        string groupName,
        bool isAdminGroup,
        IList<User> users,
        HashSet<string> userIds)
    {
        log.Info($"Attempting to find {groupName} group");
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, groupName);
        log.Info($"Successfully found {groupName} group");

        log.Info($"Attempting to read users from group {group.DistinguishedName}");
        var addedUserIds = new List<string>();
        foreach (var userPrincipal in group.Members.OfType<UserPrincipal>())
        {
            if ((userPrincipal.Enabled ?? false) && !userIds.Contains(userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName))
            {
                users.Add(new User(userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName, userPrincipal.Sid.Value, userPrincipal.DisplayName, userPrincipal.EmailAddress, isAdminGroup));
                userIds.Add(userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName.ToLower());
                addedUserIds.Add(userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName);
            }
        }
        log.Info($"Successfully read users from group {group.DistinguishedName}. Users read: {string.Join(", ", addedUserIds)}");      
}
```

**Error details**

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: While trying to resolve a cross-store reference, the SID of the target principal could not be resolved.  The error code is 1788.
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.ResolveCrossStoreRefToPrincipal(Object o)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADUtils.DirectoryEntryAsPrincipal(DirectoryEntry de, ADStoreCtx storeCtx)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.get_CurrentAsPrincipal()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollectionEnumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__95`1.MoveNext()

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask].  Post an [mcve], not an image of the code.

Comment: Apologies, didn't know about that. Let me update the question. thanks @jwdonahue

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the group contains an account from another domain that doesn't exist anymore.

When a group contains a user from an external trusted domain (not in the same AD forest) it stores a "foreign security principal" object, which contains the SID of the object. The domain that the account is on really has no idea that the account is added to a group on another domain. So if that account is deleted, the group is not automatically updated.

When you look at the `Members` collection, it tries to look up the account and give you a `UserPrincipal` object, but it cannot because the account doesn't exist anymore.